# MySQL multiple table count query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
products
    productid (int)
    name (varchar)
    price (float)

sales
    salesid (int)
    productid (int)
    time (datetime)

links
    linkid (int)
    productid (int)
    link (text)
```

Now I need a query that can display as

```
ProductID      ProductName      Sales      Links
    1           ABC               10        8
    2           XYZ               15       12
```

I need all sales count and all links count for a particular product

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What's this for, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a cross-tab query.

This [walk-through](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/index.html) on the mysql site should help.

Or [like in this tutorial](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/10/creating-crosstabs-in-mysql.html)

Comment: I've added a link to how the official mysql site solves this type of problem - that one is definitely optimized.

Comment: Cross tab queries are to convert data in rows into columns. OP needs data aggregation, not a cross tab.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.productid, p.pname AS ProductName, 
       Count(DISTINCT s.salesid) as Sales, Count(DISTINCT l.linkid) as Links
 FROM products p
   LEFT JOIN sales s ON p.productid=s.productid
   LEFT JOIN links l ON p.products=l.productid 
GROUP BY p.productid
```

Comment: What do you mean by "count same"? Do you mean the Sales and Links columns show the same count in each row?

Comment: for first join, if it is left join then count come same

Answer (score 0):

You can only use aggregate functions (like `Count()`) on the column specified in the `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise the aggregation is ambiguous. See the chapter "Ambiguous Groups" from the excellent book [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) for more reference.

In your case, the best option is to use two sub-queries:

```
SELECT p.productid as ProductID, p.pname AS ProductName, 
        (SELECT Count(*) FROM sales s WHERE p.productid=s.productid) as Sales,
        (SELECT Count(*) FROM links l WHERE p.productid=l.productid) as Links,
    FROM products p
    GROUP BY p.productid
```

Not the most efficient query ever written, but it's perfectly ok as long as the tables doesn't contain a huge number of rows and/or you run it as a periodic report and not real-time on live data.

The best thing to do is to test it for yourself and see if the performance is acceptable.